# How to create a token generation API in the Bot Composer C# solution?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm new to C# development and know we should be able to host the token generation C# api within the Bot Composer C# solution to safely use the DirectLine Secret to get a token.
Can anyone provide steps and/or sample code?

Comment: Hey @RYUB3N,  have you had a chance to look at the WebChat [/k.direct-line-token/csharp](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/main/samples/01.getting-started/k.direct-line-token/csharp) sample?

Comment: Here is a C# controller endpoint for generating a Direct Line token https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/samples/01.getting-started/k.direct-line-token/csharp/web/Controllers/DirectLineController.cs